# Does all subnets have a broadcast/network address?

Tags: network-programming

I am setting up a peer 2 peer network and i cant find if my 2 subnets will both have a network and broadcast?

x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.127 will be my first subnet's broadcast/network.
x.x.x.128 and x.x.x.255 will be the second subnet broadcast/network addresses.

or is it just x.x.x.0 and x.x.x.255 that are the broadcast/network addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined by the subnetmask, which is why you normally write IP addresses as:

```
192.168.1.24/24
```

This means the network address is `192.168.1.0` and the broadcast address `192.168.1.255`. The network part of the is /24 bits, and host id is 8 bits. For the broadcast address you always set all the host id bits to 1 (8 bits set to one = 255), and for the network address you set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Both subnet's will have the broadcast/network ip's so there will be -4 ip in the total amount of valip ip addresses in the entire subnet.